# What is the gravitational potential of an ellipsoid at $0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

What is the gravitational potential of an ellipsoid at $0$?

Given an ellipsoid: $\frac{x^2+y^2}{a^2} +\frac{z^2}{c^2} \leq 1,$ and a uniform density of mass:

Using spherical coordinates, and the transformation $(x,y,z) \rightarrow (ax,ay,cz)$
I got:
$= \int\frac{a^2c \sin \phi}{ \sqrt{ a^2sin^2\theta +c^2cos^2\theta }} $

I'm not sure how to continue from here..

Comment: it should be $= \int\int\frac{a^2c \sin \phi}{ \sqrt{ a^2sin^2\theta +c^2cos^2\theta }} d\theta d\phi$